# Mask a numpy array after a given value

Tags: python, numpy, sum, mask, jax

I have two numpy arrays like :

```
a = [False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False]

b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I need to sum over `b`, not the full array, but only until the elements with the equivalent index in `a` is `True`

In other words, I want to do 1+2+3+4+5=15 instead of 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8=36

I need an **efficient** solution, I think I need to mask all elements from `b` that are after the first `True` in `a` and make them 0.

Side note: My code is in jax.numpy and not original numpy but I guess it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a cumulated sum

```
np.sum(b[np.cumsum(a)==0])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to convert the array to a list with `.tolist()` and then apply `.index()` to obtain the index of the first `True`: `i = a.tolist().index(True)`.
Then simple slicing and summing: `total = numpy.sum(b[:i])`

Comment: Thanks for your help, however it is less efficient than the accepted one using cumulated sum

Comment: @ValentinMacé - How did you benchmark the two solutions? For your example data this solution is ~4.5x times faster than `np.cumsum`. Only solution faster I could find is `b[:a.argmax()].sum()` with a very small ~1.01x speed up. `jax.numpy` was even slower on CPU.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I am using jax.numpy and not numpy. Since I compile my code with jax.jit I don't want to convert an array to list, I should have been more clear in my question, thanks for bringing details :)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways of doing this: you could do it by constructing a mask with `cumsum` (this will also work in regular numpy):

```py
a = jnp.array([False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False])
b = jnp.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

mask = a.cumsum() == 0
b.sum(where=mask) # 15
```

Or you could find the first True index with `jnp.where` (note that the `size` argument only exists in JAX's version of `jnp.where`, not in numpy's):

```py
idx = jnp.where(a, size=1)[0][0]
b[:idx].sum() # 15
```

You might do some microbenchmarks to determine which is more efficient for the size of arrays that you're concerned with.